# How to add specific header folders to Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, unix, eclipse-cdt

I have a c++ project in a unix environment, that has a CMakeLists.txt. I used Cmake to convert it into an Eclipse project and import it in Eclipse CDT. Now, it says it can't find files in `#include "file.h"` statements.

This project has more than 20 folders and some of these folders contain the headers. I went to `Project Properties -> Include Path and Symbols` and added them there, but they don't appear in the `Includes` folder in my project, after rebuild. I don't understand why is it such a heavy task to do something so simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify include directories in the original CMakeLists.txt using the [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainclude_directories) command and re-generate the Eclipse project. This has the advantage over specifying the include directories in Eclipse because it will work for other CMake targets as well.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! This solves the problem from the root and it's much better. Worked a charm!